# Device Tree for Generic Output

Tags: gpio, hat, device-tree

I'm currently developing my first Pi Hat for a personal project. I've been exploring Device Trees and I'm quite liking the concept from the perspective that the userland code can address specific named devices rather than arbitrary GPIO pin numbers.

So far, I've mapped 3 LEDs to the `leds` target and 3 button-like inputs as `gpio-keys`.

My last GPIO (Output) pin is connected to the logical input of an external device and the Pi will use the GPIO to control whether that external device is on or off. What is the most sensible Device Tree mapping to create for such a device? I could achieve what I want to by mapping it as another LED but this feels a bit semantically questionable.

Reference: https://github.com/phil-lavin/raspi-bakelite/blob/master/eeprom/raspi-bakelite.dts